# What exactly is transmitted in the channel in lossy compression?

Tags: digital-communications, quantization, information-theory, compression, distortion

Consider the problem of lossily compressing a memoryless binary source $X 
\sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ at target Hamming distortion $D < \frac{1}{2}$. According to the analysis in *9.3.1 Example: Binary Source* from [this note](http://reeves.ee.duke.edu/information_theory/lecture9-Rate_Distortion.pdf), the marginal distribution of the optimal reconstruction $\hat{X}$ is also $\operatorname{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, which means $H(\hat{X}) = H(X) = 1$. Moreover, the rate of the compression, i.e., the mutual information between $X$ and $\hat{X}$, is $I(X; \hat{X}) = 1 - H(D) < 1$.

My question is, what exactly is stored on the disk, or more formally, transmitted through the channel? Based on the rate-distortion theory, we can compress $k$ samples from $X$ (denoted $x \in \{0, 1\}^k$) down to $k(1 - H(D))$ bits (denoted $z \in \{0, 1\}^{k(1 - H(D))}$), and the reconstruction (denoted $\hat{x} \in \{0, 1\}^k$) can achieve an expected distortion of $D$.

- What is the function that maps $x$ to $z$? I believe $z$ is essentially the "mutual information" between $X$ and $\hat{X}$, but I have no clue how to compute it.
- What is the function that maps $z$ to $\hat{x}$? I think this must be a stochastic function, because $\hat{x}$ has higher entropy than $z$ ($k > k(1 - H(D))$).

I am confused because most material on lossy compression only talks about the rate-distortion theory, without explaining how we can do lossy compression with it. After all, the entire point of lossy compression is to shorten the bitstream, and I need to know a concrete way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this topic, but my approach would be to apply vector quantization. In other words, take $n$ bits from the source and approximate them with $nR < n$ bits. Note that this is similar to conventional quantization, since you can consider the $n$ bits as a floating point number, which you then somehow "truncate" to a defined number of decimals.

There are several textbooks that go into more details about vector quantization than the note you posted above; off the top of my head I recall Gallagher's book on digital communications covers this. I'm pretty sure Proakis does as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative. I have a quick follow-up question if you don't mind. The RD theory states that the optimal reconstruction $\hat{X}$ must have distribution $\operatorname{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Does the optimal VQ reconstruction also follow this distribution? That would surprising because it means the entropy of $\hat{X}$ would be $n$ but the compressed $X$ only has $nR < n$ bits. Where did the remaining $n(1-R)$ bits of entropy in $\hat{X}$ come from given a deterministic codebook?

Comment: Not sure. Note that the $nR$ bits are still Bernoulli(1/2); maybe the theory assumes that both entropies are equal when $n$ grows without limit? Also, keep in mind that all this theory becomes interesting when the source symbol probabilities are not equal, and that Rate Distortion Theory applies to **lossy** compression.

Comment: @nalzok the reconstruction $\hat{X}$ of a scheme with deterministic codebooks is not iid.

Comment: @nalzok for example, you can make $\hat{X}$ iid, in the simplest scheme, by adding independent $n(1-R)$ bits that are independent of the other $nR$ bits. The reconstruction random source has the entropy of $n$, but the mutual information $I(X;\hat{X})$ is still $H(D)$ less stemming the distortion $D$ you are willing to sacrifice.

Answer (score 2):

The rate distortion theory simply doesn't answer the questions you ask if *how* you do it.

It does answer questions like "is this rate sufficient to get things across with at most distortion D", or, "what is the best I can do in this situation", but it has no answer to the question of *how*.

And that is pretty fine, because the how usually is concerned with how the source you actually care about is structured differently than a binary memoriless equiprobable source.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I wonder what theory answers the question of how? For simplicity, let's just assume the source I care about is really a binary memoryless equiprobable source.

Comment: Abstract concepts like «memoryless equiprobable source» are useful for developing generic theory and absolute limits. For real-world problems, there tends to be structure in information (and how that information is to be consumed in case of lossy compression) that require domain-specific knowledge.

Comment: I suspect that your memoryless equiprobably source case is nearly useless in practice.  Usually you see lossy compression used when you can identify extraneous information and compress in a way that loses that information but not the important stuff.  The two biggest examples of this that I know of are audio and image compression for consumption by humans: in both of these cases, the human perceptual system itself is less able to perceive high-frequency content, so the compression routines intentionally allow loss at high frequencies.

Comment: I don't know whether "useless" would be my choice of words, but I'd say it's a very degenerate case, where the source is discrete, hence has classical entropy of 1 bit, and zero differential entropy. Not much to do there for rate distortion theory. You lose exactly the binary entropy of your bit error probability in mutual information. Done.